# fill form using if and else in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

This is for an autofill script.

I'm using a form to get input and when submitted, it fills another form and saves automatically.

The input form has a yes or no question. If yes is selected it should return an integer value in one of the field of the main form.
If No is selected It should return another integer value.

I have used the If Else statement but it is not working.

Explained with an example below.

I created a function and called it.

```
returnStr[1] = PriorText();
```

returnStr[1] is the form field that has to be filled with the integer

the function is below.

```
function PriorText(){

if(document.getElementById('Vendortxt_2').value=='yes')
    returnStr[1] = "3"
else
    returnStr[1] = "4"
}
```

Vendortxt_2 is the ID that hold "yes" or "No" Answer

Kindly help me and correct wherever I'm wrong.

Comment: try `if(document.getElementById('Vendortxt_2').value==='yes')` or make an alert as `alert(document.getElementById('Vendortxt_2').value)`; and check it.

Comment: what does the html for *Vendortxt_2* look like ? also instead of yes / no why not just use a checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not explained what the problem is, but one problem I can see...

Making the following call `returnStr[1] = PriorText();` will not assign 3 or 4 to `returnStr[1]`; since you're not returning it as a result from the function `PriorText()`.

... and since `PriorText()` has no return statement you're probably seeing that `returnStr[1]` contains undefined: eg:

```
returnStr[1] = PriorText();
alert(returnStr[1]); // << shows the message *undefined*
```

Perhaps this fiddle helps http://jsfiddle.net/hy1e4n5k/

### Option 1

So you either need to change `PriorText()` to return the values of 3 or 4

```
function PriorText() {
    if(document.getElementById('Vendortxt_2').value=='yes')
        return "3";
    else
        return "4";
}

returnStr[1] = PriorText();
alert(returnStr[1]); // shows either 3 or 4
```

### Option2

Or you stick with the original function and not assign on call

```
function PriorText(){
    if(document.getElementById('Vendortxt_2').value=='yes')
        returnStr[1] = "3"
    else
        returnStr[1] = "4"
}

PriorText(); // just call it, don't assign result since there is no result returned!
alert(returnStr[1]); // shows either 3 or 4
```